# EntityFramework Core Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: entity-framework, timeout

In the `webAPI`, when I fetch some records,sometimes it will occur the exception

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

But sometimes it's ok and response very fast.

Why I get the exception?

Answer (score 0):

If might be that the database is locking up. Perhaps you have started a transaction on a separate thread, or in a different app, and the current call cannot complete because the transaction has not been closed.

Try killing all applications that are talking to the database, and making sure that your code is not beginning any transactions that it is not closing.

Comment: But sometimes the webapi response timed out  from OPTIONS request of the browser